# Regex to find the starting word when it matches to a string provided

Tags: python, regex

am trying to fetch strings, when a certain regex matches.

```
string1 = 'f gmat electronic: st'
string2 = 'getmat electronic: kdks'
string3 = '12 efkf electronic: nndk '
```

am failing to get the strings before electronic ..

Expected output:

```
1 - 'f gmat'
2 - 'getmat'
3 - '12 efkf'
```

I felt it is real tough and tried to ask the stackoverflow.

Code used :

```
re.findall('^((?!elect).)*', s)tring1
```

which is giving me the string after electronic

Comment: What is the regex?

Comment: @AMC added the code which I tried

Comment: Why don't you take everything before "electronic": `(.*?)\s*electronic`

Comment: @Matthias, Thanks for the help

Comment: Why use `findall()` here? I'm not sure I follow that regex, what @Matthias suggested should be alright.

Comment: @Matthias Hey, suppose if i have something like this, "hello 12333 hi this is' . I want to extract the string after the digits... result -` 'hi this is''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

string1 = 'f gmat electronic: st'
string2 = 'getmat electronic: kdks'
string3 = '12 efkf electronic: nndk '

rexp = re.compile(r"^(.*?)\s+electronic")

for n, s in enumerate((string1, string2, string3)):
  m = rexp.search(s)
  if m:
    print("%s - %s" % (n+1, repr(m.group(1))))
```

Result:

```
1 - 'f gmat'
2 - 'getmat'
3 - '12 efkf'
```

Comment: Hey, suppose if i have something like this, `"hello 12333 hi this is'` . I want to extract the string after the digits... result -` 'hi this is''`

Comment: If the original question is answered, you should mark it as answered.  But answer your 2nd question, I would use r"\d+\s*(.*)"

Comment: Hey it actually asked me to wait. hence I waited for sometime to mark it.